# ISAPI Settings not visible in IIS7

Tags: iis, iis-7, windows-7, iis-7.5

I wish to do some settings in IIS7 which could run asp.net 1.1 websites.For that some settings in **ISAPI and CGI Extensions** are required. But when Opened IIS 7 i couldn't locate any of those.
I have enable all IIS features from Programs and Features in Control Panel

I am using W7 32bit Enterprise Edition

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you select the server node in the Connections view on the left.

Are you sure the ISAPI Extensions feature is installed?

Internet Information Services > World Wide Web Services > Application Development Features > ISAPI Extensions

Comment: thanks Paul for quick comment, but i guess Server Node acc. to you is The top text that is seen in IIS. If thats the case YES i have selected that only to view ISAPI Settings.Cant see that :-(

Comment: Yes i am sure, in fact i checked once again while writing this post.It is Installed(Enabled from path given)

Comment: In Win Server 2012 R2 may also have to restart IIS

Comment: Just an additional note: I had to restart both IIS and Internet Information Server (IIS) Manager to see the ISAPI Filter icon.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done by going into `Start` -> `Program files` -> `Programs and features` -> `turn windows features on/off` ->

Then in the tree structure find

`Internet Informatiuon Service` -> `World Wide Web Services` -> `Application Development Features`

and make sure the `ISAPI Extension` and `ISAPI filter` is checked (depending on what you want).

See for more help:

http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7